# Publish a react component to npm and reuse it

Tags: npm, webpack, reactjs

I am trying to publish a basic React component to my npm registry and trying to reuse it. I think I am not following proper way to distribute my react component. Here's what I have:

This is the directory structure:

```
MyReactPOC
    -> main.jsx
    -> .npmrc
    -> package.json
    -> webpack.config.js
```

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hello from MyComponent!!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@pankaj/my-component",
  "version": "1.0.7",
  "description": "POC for importing a component",
  "main": "./dist/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "prepublish": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "my git repo"
  },
  "author": "Pankaj",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "~15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "~6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "~6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "~6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.24.1",
    "webpack": "~2.4.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.jsx',
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

I import the module in another project using `import MyComponent from '@pankaj/my-component'`.

When I use this component like

I get the following error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the
>   file it's defined in.

Please help me understand the right way to distribute the react components so that they can be used by other projects within my org.

Here is how I use this component:

**ComponentUse.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyComponent from '@pankaj/my-component';

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I have an index.html that has the 'root' div.

Comment: Try doing `console.log(MyComponent)` after importing it to check what is actually getting imported. You might be failing to actually import it and trying to call `createElement` on `undefined`.

Comment: @PedroCastilho `component is : [object Object]`. Is there a way I can see MyComponent in watch?

Comment: Your problem is that your render function has no return statement, so you get `undefined` when you try to render it.

Comment: I even added that as per one of the answers.. My bad I forgot to put that in here. But the error did not change even after putting return. Edited the question to reflect what I have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every react component needs a return statement. Add a return statement in your render function and it should work.

```
...
render() {
     return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

You cannot directly render to the Dom from your react component, instead return it so that react can work with it.

In webpack, specify your output file as a library using output.library https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#output-library

Comment: Tried that, still no luck :(

Comment: Can you add the code where you are using the component.

Comment: added. I have even tried `import MyComponent from '@pankaj/my-component/dist.bundle'` to no avail

Comment: Check out my edit. You need to destructure the component. Try it out.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Let me put the entire code somewhere.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875467/importing-custom-npm-package-results-in-empty-null-object

And this https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#output-library

Comment: Thanks a ton. `libraryTarget: 'umd'` was the key.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a full Medium story because I had the same issue as you and there is no information about it.
Check it out: https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce

The main fix is to add `libraryTarget: 'umd'` in the webpack.config.js file

Comment: Well, there are a few links here and there, but I agree there was nothing that explains the full story until you wrote it. Good Job man!!

Answer (score 0):

If you export with es6 syntax with babel, your component will be in MyComponent.default namespace. To avoid this you should install:

```
npm i --save-dev babel-plugin-add-module-exports in your .babelrc?
```

and add it to the babel conf:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["add-module-exports"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After several days of searching, I believe [microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) effortlessly achieves this. Below is my build command:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "microbundle build --globals react=React,react-dom=ReactDOM --jsx cloneElement,createContext,isValidElement,useContext,useReducer --jsxFragment Fragment --jsxImportSource react",
    "dev": "microbundle watch"
  },
```